# Autofill handle behaving differently in two columns

Tags: excel

I'm working on a spreadsheet where values entered in two columns will often (but not always) be the same for the entire column. When dragging down the column with the fill handle, however, one column copies data and the other increments it and I don't understand why. The column that increments is also copying borders down the column, the other column isn't. Under the formatting window both columns have the exact same settings (other than background color, but I tried changing that and it had no impact), why is it behaving this way and is there any way to change the default behavior for each column?
Note: I've tried ctrl+dragging the columns, and the "Extract Volume" column copies values correctly, but still is copying borders while the "Dilution" column is just copying values.

Before dragging handle:

[image]

After dragging handle:

[image]

Comment: For me, CTRL+DRAG gives the incrementing behavior.  If I just drag `50` down, I get a column of `50` and no increment.  If you want to ensure a pattern, you can add a second `50` and select both before dragging down.  Regarding formatting, is it possible that the blue cell has a top border whereas the grey one does not?  By default, formatting is copied which means that somehow those two cells have different formats.  You can verify by clearing all formatting (ALT+H+E+F or `Clear->Formats`) from the blue cell and making sure a bottom border is on the `extract volume` header only.

Comment: The borders are the same on both columns, so that isn't the source of the problem. I did notice, though, that the Extract Volume column in my spreadsheet is composed of merged cells, whereas the Dilutions column is only a single cell. This was for spacing issues with the rest of the spreadsheet. Unmerging the cells in the Extract Volume column fixed the behavior. Any way I can keep the cells merged but also keep the unmerged behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter 50 in the first two rows of `Extract Volume` and then drag it down that should work.

I have a feeling that the datatypes for both columns are different and that's why you're getting this error.

Another approach is, Enter 50 in the first row, Copy it, highlight the rows you wish to fill and paste.

Comment: Here's what's weirding me out, when I do that it does copy the value correctly but it's still copying the border for the top of the cell. The formatting for each column is general, is datatype separate from that?

Comment: The reason the formatting is copying is that the `Dilution` column has a bottom border for the header whereas the `Exact Volume` column has a top border for the first `50` If you change that, the formatting problem should be solved. Not too sure why they copy differently though. In General it should both work the same way. I'm actually surprised `Dilution` copies without increments. Normally excel always increments when you Autofill with just one row.

Comment: The borders are the same on both cells, that was what I checked first. I tentatively have found the problem, though, the Extract Volume column is composed of merged cells, the Dilution column isn't. Unmerging the cells fixes the behavior. Not sure why that changes the behavior of the autofill though.